# django server cant find sqlite3 dbapi2 on windows machine

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-import, django-database

I'm trying to start a django server but I keep getting an error that looks like this:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): cannot import name dbapi2
```

The closest thing I can find to my issue is [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/PhH3-6oHAD0/CAtc9WvpQRsJ). His solution doesn't really work for me as I cant use symlinks and I've tried moving my system environment variables around but maybe there is something I'm not seeing. Here are my sys env variables:

```
C:\workspace\pension;C:\workspace\shark;C:\workspace\seal;C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends;
```

And this is my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
},
'PROD': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'master',
    'HOST': 'SECNYSQ01',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
        'dsn': 'SECOR_SQL_01',
    },
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600
},
'UAT': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'master',
    'HOST': 'SECORSQL01',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
        'dsn': 'SECOR_SQL_DEV',
    },
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600
},
'DEV': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'master',
    'HOST': 'SECORSQL01',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'driver': 'SQL Native Client',
        'dsn': 'SECOR_SQL_DEV',
    },
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600
},}
```